# What does this function do

Tags: c++, function, heap

Here's a program of a comparator which I am supposed to base a priority queue on.

```
#ifndef COMPARATOR_H
#define COMPARATOR_H

#include "Point.h"

class mycomparison
{
 Point dest;
 public:
    mycomparison(Point *d)
    {
        dest.setRow(d->getRow());
        dest.setColumn(d->getColumn());
    }

    bool operator() (const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.distanceFrom(dest) > rhs.distanceFrom(dest));
    }
};

#endif
```

That is, object dest of point contains the value distance, to which the array members of binary min heap are compared and ordered accordingly.

I need to know how does this function bool operator() (const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const, work? I know it takes two objects and compares them returns true or false. But I am not able to formulate the function call. I keep getting the error:

In member function ‘virtual void PriorityQueueArray::push(const Point&)’: PriorityQueueArray.cpp:57:17: error: expected type-specifier before ‘(’ token

Here's my function call along with the desired header files.

```
#include "PriorityQueueADT.h"
#include "comparator.h"
#include "Point.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

 class PriorityQueueArray : public PriorityQueueADT {
 private:

 Point *Array;
 Point *P;
 int siz;
 int num;

 public:
    PriorityQueueArray(Point *destination);

    void push (const Point& val);
    bool empty();
    Point top();
    void pop();
    int size();

};

void PriorityQueueArray::push (const Point& val)
{
 mycomparison M(P);
 Point temp;
 if(empty()){
    num=1;
    Array[num]=val;
 }

else{
    if(num==siz-1){
        Point *Arr=new Point[2*siz];
        for(int i=1; i<siz; i++)
            Arr[i]=Array[i];

        Array=Arr; siz=2*siz;
        }

    num++;
    Array[num]=val;

    if(num==2){
        if(M.operator(Array[2], Array[1])){
        temp=Array[2];
        Array[2]=Array[1];
        Array[1]=temp;
        }
    }

    else{
        int j=num;
        while(j>1){
            if(M.operator (Array[j], Array[j/2])){
                temp=Array[j];
                Array[j]=Array[j/2];
                Array[j/2]=temp;
                j=j/2;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    return;

    }
```

I just need to know the syntax for a function call to operator().

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/function_call_operator_overloading.htm

Comment: `M(Array[j], Array[j/2])`.